# PBS broadcast series about spaceship stuck into earth and extending into space?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

Back in the 70's or 80's I used to watch PBS late night and they'd have Doctor Who and other Sci Fi series on.

There was a series the I've been trying to find with a large 'generation' ship. 
As I recall the ship had apparently crashed into the planet so that one end was like prehistoric cavemen and the other end was highly advanced. The main cast travelled from one end of the ship to the other during the series.  I don't think it was Starlost because I remember scenes where it showed the ship attached to the planet yet out into space as well.

Anyone remember this?

Comment: A 60+ mile long spaceship with one end stuck into the Earth?!

Comment: You might try looking at the Wikipedia page I've linked at the end of this comment.  It has one of the most exhaustive lists I have seen of Sci Fi TV shows & cartoons from all eras from US, Canada, Europe, Japan, and is organized by genres:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_television_programs_by_genre

Comment: The list of "telefantasies" (a term covering both sci fi and fantasy) [here](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/john.seymour1/telefantasylist/whatistelefantasy.html) is also pretty exhaustive, just click a decade to see all the ones they list from different countries in that decade.